# React RTK query Mutation can return value?

Tags: reactjs, mutation, rtk-query

Is is possible to get the response of endpoint in React RTK Query **Mutation** .
I have a one mutation which insert into DB and I need to get the ID which inserted. in my api :

```
addRecord: build.mutation({
        query(data) {
            return {
                url: base + 'myControler/SaveDataAsync',
                method: 'post',
                data: data,
            }
        },
    }),
```

and in my component after import my hook I call it like

```
const [addRecord] = useAddRecordMutation();
```

and then in my submit function is use it like

```
    const handleSubmitCustom = async (values) => {

       await addRecord(values);

    }
```

which I need the return value of  await addRecord(values);

Comment: for any example to make sense you need to show how you are calling the mutation in your code

Comment: Hi Phry , Thank you for your comment , I already added more detail to my question . many thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just do

```js
    const handleSubmitCustom = async (values) => {

       try {
          const returned = await addRecord(values).unwrap();
       } catch (error) {
         // you can handle errors here if you want to
       }

    }
```

Comment: Interesting. How come we in your answer don't use `data` as described in the docs https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#frequently-used-mutation-hook-return-values? Why not somthing like this?
`const [addRecord, { data: data }] = useAddRecordMutation()`

Comment: @saner That would become available as a new variable called `data` during the next render, but you want to immediately continue working with it in the same closure, right?

Comment: Yes, true I noticed this behaviour as I was coding.

Comment: and how about `'error' is of type 'unknown'.`

Comment: @AmirRezvani caught errors in TypeScript are always `unknown`, since you can't really know what they are before closely looking at them. An error could be caused by anything and vary wildly in content.